# Mid-loop modification java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

In this loop:

```
while(a < 100){
    a=a+1;
    for(i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        if(x < arr[i]){
            arr2[i] = arr2[i] - z;
            x = x - z;
            if(x > arr[i]) break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `i`th element may be greater than `x` causing the break but `i+1` may
be less than `x` and I want to subtract `x` from `i+1`, how can I make the loop just skip `arr[i]` and move on to `arr[i+1]` without breaking the loop altogether and without starting an iteration from the top?

An example of my output is `arr2=(0,0,0,2,0,0,5)` where `x=3` so my loop terminates at 2 because its less than 3 but I still want to subtract from 5.

Comment: you mean, to use continue instead of break?

Comment: doesn't continue start a new iteration of the loop?

Comment: What is the reason for this loop? What are you trying to accomplish in the grand scheme of your program?

Comment: I've read through 2 tutorials that said continues starts the loop from the begining instead of just skipping an element? are you for sure?

Comment: The grand scheme is to have all elements of an array within the parameter that is listed in another array so arr1[i] needs to be within x distance of arr2[i] only if variable x is greater than the sum of elements arr2[i]

Comment: Sorry eric, this problem description is making my brain hurt.  Please edit your question to show an example input and output.

Comment: Some commentary on the program would help. The while loop does nothing other than loop for (100 minus the original value of a) times. A *for* loop often better expresses this thought.

The variable z appears to be a quantity to be deducted from one or more arr2[] elements, those whose corresponding arr[] element is greater than or equal to the current value of x.

It may be that the while loop should check to see if x has become negative, or possibly not. The supplied code could be confusingly nearly correct, or it could be terribly wrong; it really depends upon the goal of the code.

Comment: Continue breaks out of the current iteration of the loop and _continues_ with the next iteration.

Comment: Sorry for not having an example at first, I added one in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you maybe intend this, but I cannot imagine what you try to achieve.
Try the algorithm on paper.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (x < arr[i]) {
        arr2[i] -= z;
        x -= z;
        if (x <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        // Continue with smaller x (assuming z > 0) for rest of arr.
    }
}
```

---

***On the for loop:***

```
for (START; CONDITION; STEP) {
    STMT1;
    continue;
    STMT2;
 }
```

is equivalent to:

```
 START;
 loop:
     if (!CONDITION) {
         goto endloop;
     }
     STMT1;
     goto step;
     STMT2;
 step:
     STEP;
     goto loop;
 endloop:
```